# How can I style it with @emotion/styled? Old makestyles from mui issue

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I'm trying to set up my style via @emotion, since makestyles were removed in React 18. I changed the code in this way in line with my research, but I still can't see any change in my page.

Normally it should look like this:
[image]

But it looks like this:
[image]

App.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Typography, AppBar } from '@mui/material';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import VideoPlayer from './components/VideoPlayer';
import Options from './components/Options';
import Notification from './components/Notification';


// * Style dosyası bağlandı
const useStyles = styled(theme => ({
  appBar: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: '30px 100px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '600px',
    border: '2px solid black',

    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      width: '90%',
    },
  },
  image: {
    marginLeft: '15px',
  },
  wrapper: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
  },
}));

const App = () => {
  // * Style dosyası çağırıldı
  //* className olarak elementlere tanımlandı
  const classes=useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position='static' color='inherit'>
        <Typography variant='h2' align='center'>
          Video Conferencing App
        </Typography>
      </AppBar>
      <VideoPlayer />
      <Options>
        <Notification />
      </Options>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples are presented below: One with `styled`, one without. It is not necessary to use `styled`. As you can see from the examples the code without `styled` is less verbose and (in my opinion) easier to understand.

In the examples the `VideoPlayer`, `Options` and `Notification` components were replaced with `div` and `span` for testing.

### Example with styled

```
import React from 'react';

import { Typography, AppBar } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

// import VideoPlayer from './components/VideoPlayer';
// import Options from './components/Options';
// import Notification from './components/Notification';

const theme = createTheme();

// * Style dosyası bağlandı
const appBarStyles = {
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: '30px 100px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '600px',
    border: '2px solid black',

    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
        width: '90%'
    }
};

const imageStyles = {
    marginLeft: '15px'
};

const wrapperStyles = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%'
};

const App = () => {
    // * Style dosyası çağırıldı
    //* className olarak elementlere tanımlandı
    // const classes=useStyles();
    const AppBarStyled = styled(
        ( { className, ...props } ) => (
            <AppBar className={ className } position='static' color='inherit'>
                <Typography variant='h2' align='center'>
                    Video Conferencing App
                </Typography>
            </AppBar>
        )
    )( ( { theme, ...props } ) => appBarStyles );

    const AppStyled = styled(
        ( { className, ...props } ) => (
            <div className={ className }>
                <AppBarStyled />
                <div>Video Player</div>
                <div>
                    <span>Options</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    )( ( { theme, ...props } ) => wrapperStyles );

    return (
        <AppStyled />
    )
}

export default App;
```

### Example without styled

```
import React from 'react';

import { Typography, AppBar } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
// import styled from '@emotion/styled';

// import VideoPlayer from './components/VideoPlayer';
// import Options from './components/Options';
// import Notification from './components/Notification';

const theme = createTheme();

// * Style dosyası bağlandı
const appBarStyles = {
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: '30px 100px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '600px',
    border: '2px solid black',

    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
        width: '90%'
    }
};

const imageStyles = {
    marginLeft: '15px'
};

const wrapperStyles = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%'
};

const App = () => {
    // * Style dosyası çağırıldı
    //* className olarak elementlere tanımlandı
    // const classes=useStyles();

    return (
        <div style={ wrapperStyles }>
            <AppBar sx={ appBarStyles } position='static' color='inherit'>
                <Typography variant='h2' align='center'>
                     Video Conferencing App
                </Typography>
            </AppBar>
            <div>Video Player</div>
            <div>
                <span>Options</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```